# Can't make translate3d Z property to work

Tags: css, translate3d

I am traying to use:

```
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,500px,300px);
```

X and Y properties working just fine, but Z (300px),just won't work. Here is the [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54Pa7/12/). What am I doing wrong? I tried both Chrome 24 and Canary 25
Thanks for your support...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing -webkit-perspective parameter on the parent element. When I added this it started working just like it should.

Answer (score 4):

According to [WebKit Blog](http://www.webkit.org/blog/386/3d-transforms/) ,

> translate3d(x, y, z), translateZ(z) Move the element in x, y and z,
>   and just move the element in z. Positive z is towards the viewer.
>   Unlike x and y, the z value cannot be a percentage.

You'd need anther element to get the effect. I added a few to your code.

HTML

```
<div class="coin1">
    <div class="coin2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.coin1{
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
    width:80px;
    height:40px;
    background:#fc0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1,0,0,-55deg) rotate3d(0,0,1,30deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.coin1 .coin2
{
    background:#444;
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,150px);
}
```

It seems working and JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/S5dYf/).

Frankly, I don't have much knowledge about the translate3d and but recently found some links about CSS3 Transformation while learning CSS3.

- [CSS3 Transformation](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transforms/)
- [Hardware-Accelerated CSS](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/21/play-with-hardware-accelerated-css/)
- [CSS3 3D Transform](http://www.pageresource.com/css3/3d-transforms-tutorial/)
- [CSS3 Translate3d -Z Value](http://jsfiddle.net/davechiu/zrVVr/)